# How to get distinct value of a field with URI query of elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

How to get distinct value of a field with URI query of elasticsearch, Plus how can we remove size constraint and get all the indexed data?

Comment: What do you mean by `distinct` value of field here? Please elaborate with an example.

Comment: distinct value as in if I have a field instance which has duplicate values for many records but I just want to display the record of one value once only!

Comment: Suppose name field has 'Ramesh' in two documents you want to show only one document. Is that what you want?

Comment: yes that is exactly what I want, but with URI query

Comment: You have to aggregation for that and I don't think if you can use aggregation with URI query

Comment: yeah I read about aggregation but I wanted this in URI query not the request body query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`...?source={...}` query parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string) in order to send your DSL query in the URI string if needed.

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/_search?source={"aggs":{"unique":{"terms":{"field":"my_field"}}}}
```